# Fetching list of foreign key in a single statement MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all units related to a product in a single query

Would appreciate any help

```
Table Product 

ID  Product_Name
1    Tomato 
2    Banana
3    Sugar
4    Potatto
```

```
Table Units 

ID ProductID Quantity Unit
1     3         1      KG
2     3         2      KG
3     3         3      KG
4     3         5      KG
```

```
Expected Result 

 ID 1, Product_Name Sugar, [Quantity 1 Unit KG] [Quantity 2 Unit KG] [Quantity 3 Unit KG] [Quantity 5 Unit KG]
```

Comment: where does other three columns come from???

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I want 

ID 1, Product_Name Sugar, [Quantity 1 Unit KG] [Quantity 2 Unit KG] [Quantity 3 Unit KG] [Quantity 5 Unit KG]

Comment: Do you want that result showing the `Quantity` columns horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Horizontally, only one row output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After joining `Products` and `Units`, you can `group` the result `by` product columns, then using the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function get the desired unit list for the product:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Product_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[Quantity:', u.Quantity, '  Unit:',u.Unit,']')) as UnitList
FROM Units u JOIN Product p
ON p.ID = u.ProductId
WHERE p.ID = 3 // or any other product id
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Product_Name
```

Comment: I wanted to fetch the Product, in product i wanted to have the units like in a list.

Comment: I updated the answer and provided a solution using `join`.

Comment: But now i am getting 4 rows as output. i wanted 1 row output